# Does cin.ignore with a limit continue discarding new input?

Tags: c++, stdin

I'm trying to learn C++, and have fallen into a rabbithole with some `cin` behavior I can't understand. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;

    // Get valid input
    do
    {
        if (!cin)
        {
            // Clear error state and flush any garbage input
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
        }

        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        cin >> num;
    } while (!cin);

    // Echo back what we heard
    cout << "You entered: " << num << "\n";

    cin.get();
}
```

The problem here is that the first time I enter invalid input (e.g. some alphabetic characters) the program gets stuck on the `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max())` statement. I can continue to type stuff (including newlines), the program just never proceeds past that statement.

To my understanding, this suggests that if the first argument to `cin.ignore` exceeds the current size of the buffer, any future characters (up until the provided limit) will keep getting discarded. Is this correct? If it is correct, how do I just clear the input buffer without affecting future input?

---

Note: For some reason, using `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`, and adding a `cin.ignore()` after the `cin >> num` makes the code work correctly. This is just to clarify I am aware this possibility exists, but I'm still interested in understanding what is going wrong in the code above (where the `\n` delimiter isn't specified).

Comment: You're discarding characters indefinitely (lots of them) until you hit that `max()` limit or an EOF is found.

Comment: @MarcoA. Lets say I typed `sdqwd` instead of a number. The buffer is now in a fail state and has 6 characters (my garbage and a newline) in it. Once `ignore` removes all of those, doesn't it hit EOF?

Comment: Nope, it will when you enter the end-of-file character (usually Ctrl-Z)

Comment: @MarcoA. Ah, so I was misunderstanding when the input stream ends. So how do I clear just what's in the buffer?

Comment: You flush the buffer with ignore, but since you're entering numbers (and a newline is used), you should discard until a newline is found. `clear()` will just reset the error flags

Comment: @MarcoA. Is there no way to just skip exactly what is currently in the buffer without giving a specific delimiter?

Comment: Sure, you could use `getline` and skip exactly the number of characters entered, this mechanism might seem contrived but it's actually flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clearing any error flag and then discarding additional characters until the hard limit of `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` or an `EOF` character (you can usually enter one with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>) is hit. Therefore it is, as you suspected, continuously discarding your input.

A fixed version of your code could just discard characters until a newline is found

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;

  // Get valid input
  do
  { 
    if (cin.fail())
    {
      // Clear error state and flush any garbage input
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;

  } while (cin.fail());

  // Echo back what we heard
  cout << "You entered: " << num << "\n";

  cin.get();
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/ebQrCU)</kbd>

And possibly a more idiomatic and compact version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;

  // Get valid input
  while( (cout << "Please enter a number: ") && !(cin >> num) )
  {
    cout << "Invalid number entered" << endl;
    // Clear error state and flush any garbage input
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
  }

  // Echo back what we heard
  cout << "You entered: " << num << "\n";

  cin.get();
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/UhgCCX)</kbd>

As you noted `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` might be an easier solution since it will discard exactly the number of characters available to read in the stream.

Comment: Accepting this since it is probably the correct way to do it. I just found `cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());` also works though :)

Comment: That might probably be an easier solution: it will clear the number of characters in the buffer without doing any manual counting. I'll edit this in for completeness' sake